# Hibernate alias issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to pass location.locationId in my alias but the alias picks up the bases entity. any clue how to do it?

```
Criteria cri= session.createCriteria(User.class)
                .setFetchMode("class1",FetchMode.JOIN )
                .createAlias("class1", "idmp").createAlias("idmp.class2", "idm").setReadOnly(isreadonly);

        if(locationId != null){
            cri.setFetchMode("location",FetchMode.JOIN )
                    .createAlias("idm.location", "location");
            cri.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("GetAncestryOf({alias}.locationId) REGEXP CONCAT('(^|.*,)',"+locationId+",'(,.*|$)')"));
```

I tried everything and nothing worked.

The outcome should be like

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from user this_ inner join idmapper idmp1_ on this_.mappedId=idmp1_.mappedId inner join identifier idm2_ on idmp1_.mappedId=idm2_.mappedId inner join location location3_ on idm2_.locationId=location3_.locationId inner join role role4_ on idmp1_.roleId=role4_.roleId where GetAncestryOf(location3_.locationId) REGEXP CONCAT('(^|.*,)',384949,'(,.*|$)')
```